# How to rewrite this js script to set the width of a text field to 50%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, width

I use [this script](http://www.fittextjs.com/) and I want to set width of my text to 50% instead of 100% using it. 
Here we go:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.fitText = function( kompressor, options ) {

    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
        settings = $.extend({
          'minFontSize' : Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
          'maxFontSize' : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
        }, options);

    return this.each(function(){    

      var $this = $(this);    

      var resizer = function () {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };

      resizer();

      $(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);

    });    
  };    
})( jQuery );
```

Any ideas how to rewrite it?

Comment: don´t you have to set compressor at 0.5? i.e $(selector).itText(0.5)

Comment: You're right. I changed compressor to 1.57 and works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just make text container to be 50% of required width.

```
<head>
    <script>
        jQuery(".half-width-text").fitText(10);
    </script>
    <style>
        .half-width-text {
            width: 50%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="full-width-container">
        <div class="half-width-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you need to avoid new classes and rewrite the script, you can add width to DOM element, just like it does with font-size

```
  var resizer = function () {
    $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
    $this.css('width', '50%');
  };
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc8ebted/10/)
it uses css, but there is a commented line if you need js. See how text width changes when you reduce window's width - it always half screen.